# Rabbitmq set user only sub

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

How to add a user can only Subscribe but not Publish?

on Publish/Subscribe https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to official documentation regarding access control: 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Especially the "Authorisation: How Permissions Work" section.